# How properly convert char to String and pass String in method?

Tags: java

I need to pass the String in the end of method in order to print String directly in main method, but when I did below, I receive just this one
`[Ljava.lang.String;@135fbaa4`

```
public static String businessLogic(String[] words) {
    for (String word : words) {
        char[] arrayWordInChar = word.toCharArray();
        int wordLength = word.length();
        for (int i = 0, j = wordLength - 1; i < j; ) {
            if (!Character.isAlphabetic(arrayWordInChar[i]))
                i++;
            else if (!Character.isAlphabetic(arrayWordInChar[j]))
                j--;
            else
                swapLetters(arrayWordInChar, i++, j--);
        }
        arrayWordInChar.toString();
    }
    return Arrays.toString(words);
}




public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        businessLogic(words);

        System.out.println(words);

}
}
```

I have been confused with this question for almost 2 days, what's the problem?

Comment: @Tim I think you meant `System.out.println(businessLogic(words));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get "[Ljava.lang.String;@135fbaa4" because words is `String[]`, you can change the code as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    //businessLogic(words);
    System.out.println(businessLogic(words));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.toString(str)

String Constructor

String.valueOf() or String.copyValueOf()

Answer (score 0):

First, add assignment to `words` array by `words = businessLogic(words);`

To print your arraylist elements, you can do one of the following :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

or

```
for(String word : words){
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

businessLogic method returns a string but you are not assigning it to any String variable and in your System.out you are printing array words as a string.

```
System.out.println(businessLogic(words));
```

above line will print your desired output.